# Calculate difference of values between two timestamps and assign difference to each row in the results

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=12ae08cbb2943e6895108bc027da8c97)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    plan_week VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, plan_week, quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "CW01", "125"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "CW01", "300"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "CW01", "700"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_D", "CW01", "900"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "CW01", "570"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "CW02", "150"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_E", "CW02", "325");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
time_stamp   |   product     |      plan_week   |    quantity   |    difference_quantity
-------------|---------------|------------------|---------------|-------------------
2020-01-01   |   Product_A   |        CW01      |       125     |          445
2020-03-15   |   Product_A   |        CW01      |       570     |          445
             |               |                  |               |
2020-01-01   |   Product_B   |        CW01      |       300     |         -300
             |               |                  |               |
2020-01-01   |   Product_C   |        CW01      |       700     |         -550
2020-03-15   |   Product_C   |        CW02      |       150     |         -550
             |               |                  |               |
2020-01-01   |   Product_D   |        CW01      |       900     |         -900
2020-03-15   |   Product_E   |        CW02      |       325     |          325
```

---

In the above result I want to calculate the `difference` between two `time_stamps` and assign this `difference` to each row per `product` and `plan_week` as you can see in the column `difference_quantity`.

So far I have this query which compares the two `time_stamps` and returns the max-quantity between the both of them:

```
SELECT 
time_stamp,
product,
plan_week,
quantity,
MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product) AS max_quantity
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

However, I have no clue how I can modify this query so instead of the max-quantity the `difference_quantity` is displayed. 
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue with the `+/- signs` by calculating the difference between the `time_stamps` in a seperate table and then use a `LEFT JOIN` to this table:

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f6f3c03ae4050f1fd656fa1c67567707)**

```
SELECT 
op.time_stamp,
op.product,
op.plan_week,
op.quantity,
t2.difference_quantity
  
FROM operations op
LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT
  product,
  (sum(time_stamp_02) - sum(time_stamp_01)) AS difference_quantity
  FROM
    (SELECT 
    product,
    SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-01-01' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-03-15' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_02
    FROM operations 
    GROUP BY 1) t1
  GROUP BY 1) t2 ON t2.product = op.product

GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to be describing logic like this:

```
SELECT o.*,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY product) = 2
             THEN MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product) - MIN(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product)
             ELSE quantity
        END) AS difference_quantity
FROM operations o
ORDER BY product, time_stamp;
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the 300, 550 and 900 as negative numbers?

Comment: @Akina: I tried but could not make it work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1da155738880e83d4d36a4c0b1c58e94

Comment: @Michi . . . It is better to ask a *new* question rather than invalidating answers by editing an already-answered question.

Comment: The -300 and the -550 were arelady there before I edited the question. The minus sign of the -900 was missing and I edited so the expected results are fully correct.

Answer (score 0):

Non-optimized step-by-step solution. All CTEs may be easily compacted into one CTE.

Assumes that source table stores two distinct date values strictly.

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT time_stamp FROM operations),
cte2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM operations),
cte3 AS (SELECT * FROM cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2),
cte4 AS (SELECT cte3.*, operations.plan_week, COALESCE(operations.quantity, 0) quantity
         FROM cte3 LEFT JOIN operations USING (time_stamp, product)),
cte5 AS (SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp DESC)
                  -FIRST_VALUE(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp ASC) difference
         FROM cte4)
SELECT * FROM cte5 WHERE plan_week IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 2,1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=76b8a86c3107a2956be36004bec6d444)